# Arduino Killing USB-C Mini Dock

Tags: arduino-mega, usb

I've been having some issues with my Arduino Mega Board. I built a PCB that would sense LM35 reading, low-pass filter it and send it to A0 into the Arduino. This is the input for a PID controller based on Brett Beauregard library. The schematics is really simple, a voltage divider after de PWM output, that polarizes the base of a TIP 122, causing current to close the circuit for a wound wire resistor.

1)
I was feeding the PCB board with 12V 2A switching supply (but not the arduino). On the other side, my PC was connected to a USB-C / USB mini dock to the Arduino, and the Arduino conected to the PCB board ( LM35 Output and PWM Input).
While using it my computer lagged a lot, but I didn't do anything, untill it killed my mini dock's USB port.( the power supply GND was connected to the Arduino's GND)

2) I did a new PCB board, filtering even more the LM35 signal, and doing some extra changes. While doing some examinations for the filter (succesfully) and using a lab's regulated power supply for the PCB (12V), everything went okay...Untill I wanted to examine if the PWM signal was causing any noise into the LM35 reading, so I started apply the PWM signal to a header pin in the PCB. After a while my computer stopped recognizing the Arduino and finally killed a second USB mini dock.

I'm pretty sure there's not a shortcircuit or any stupid mistake... but I cannot find whats going on.

[image: Schematics: the 2nd pin of the P1 socket was not being used, neither the fan one in P2. Wire wound resistor was not connected in the respective header pin]

Comment: Why is the +12V net connected to the Arduino power plug. And how did you connect your Arduino power plug  to the PCB? I do not say it's an error. I simply do not understand what happens there. ;-)

Comment: I think the electrical engineering stackexchange might be a better place for this question.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/